# Can `git log --pretty=format` transform output via regex?

Tags: git

Our merge commit messages look like this (GitHub creates this format automatically):

```
Merge pull request #123 from repo/branch-a

Some change (title of the PR)
```

I can use `--pretty=format:"%s: %b"` (`%s` is "subject", `%b` is "body") to get an output like this:

```
* Merge pull request #123 from repo/branch-a: Some change
* Merge pull request #456 from repo/branch-b: Another change
```

I'd like to transform the output to this:

```
* PR #123: Some change
* PR #456: Another change
```

Can this be done via `--pretty` alone or do I need to pipe it to another program that will make the transformation? What would you do to get the same coloring and pagination (via `$PAGER`; `less` in my case) that plain `git log` does?

---

**UPDATE**: the full command I run is this:

```
git log --color --graph --pretty=format:\"%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %b: %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset\" --abbrev-commit --merges --first-parent
```

Comment: `git log --pretty=format:"%s: %b"` won't have any colors in any case, so that seems like a non-issue. Just pipe your output through `sed`.

Comment: @larsks The actual command I run contains colors and looks like this: `git log --color --graph --pretty=format:\"%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %b: %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset\" --abbrev-commit --merges --first-parent`

Comment: I think you're going to have to do some post-processing.  I don't think the `git` command has the ability to arbitrarily reformat a commit subject.  Have you tried passing your current output through `sed`?  I would expect that the special characters for color would make it through `sed` if you don't cause it to mess with them, and so you'd get colored output even after passing your output through `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no: `--pretty` has a lot of format directives, but none of them allow regex substitution.

> What would you do to get the same coloring and pagination (via `$PAGER`; `less` in my case) that plain git log does?

Plain `git log`, with no options at all, does some color switching you can't quite get with any pretty format (I consider this a very minor bug).  The main thing to get color controls out of `git log` when piping `git log` output (so as to do regex work or whatever) is to use the `--color=always` switch.  To get the pager to run, use `git var GIT_PAGER` to find which pager to run, then run it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
YOURCOMMAND | sed 's/Merge pull request \#\([1-9]\).*\:\(.*\)/PR #\1: \2/g'
```

Just no colors here